# NVIDIA GeForce GT 240M running hot on Kubuntu 64bit

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, gpu

I'm using a Packard Bell - EasyNote TJ65 (64bit Core) with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 240M.
I know my computer is not the newest nor fastest model but until now I never had Problems running Linux Kubuntu 14.04 (LTS) 32bit-Version.

Now I changed (total new instalation) to the Kubuntu 14.04 64bit-Version (need it in order to be able to run Autodesk Maya). Since I installed the 64bit-Version (which I though even should be running better on a 64bit-Core) the GPU runs hot... very hot! Until finaly at 106°C Linux shuts down without warning.

I watched Psensor for testing (without doing anything all Temps stay at about 50°C .. but even than the GPU already is at 65-70°C)
When I start a YouTube-Video the GPU temperature raises within 5 minutes up to 106°C and Linux goes down.

I already tried the given NVIDIA drivers
-NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.113 from nvidia-331 (Recommended Driver)
- X.Org-X-Server -- Nouveau from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (didn't work .. never accepted my change when I choose this one)
-NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.125 from nvidia-304
and the second one I use actually seems at least to heaten up a bit slower -_- haa haa

Anyone an idea? I really would like not having to reinstall 32bit again and having to boot up even slower sucking Windows to use Maya (Maya itself works fine on Kubuntu .. just the GPU problem which happens with everything I do in 64bit-Version)

(tools like fancontrol won't work for me because it seems it isn't controlled by PWM)